# URL in External MTurk ?ion having query param

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, xsd, xsd-validation, mechanicalturk

How to pass External URL for MTurk for creating External Question if the URL has two or more params.

Ex-

```
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd">
<ExternalURL>https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturkexternalquestion/untitled.html?color=Red&product_asin=B0100RUSI6</ExternalURL>
<FrameHeight>800</FrameHeight>
</ExternalQuestion>
```

I am getting XML validation for the above external URL. But if I use one query param in the URL it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to escape the & parameter (e.g., &) for it to be valid XML. Here's a complete Ruby code sample that works and demonstrates this:

```rb
require 'aws-sdk'

aws_access_key_id = 'YOUR_ACCESS_ID'
aws_secret_access_key = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'
endpoint = 'https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'

# Uncomment this line to use in production
# endpoint = 'https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

#credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
mturk = Aws::MTurk::Client.new(endpoint: endpoint) #, credentials: credentials, region: region)

QUESTION = <<END
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd">
<ExternalURL>https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturkexternalquestion/untitled.html?color=Red&amp;product_asin=B0100RUSI6</ExternalURL>
<FrameHeight>800</FrameHeight>
</ExternalQuestion>
END

response = mturk.create_hit(title: "Example HIT", 
                            description: "Example HIT", 
                            lifetime_in_seconds: 60 * 60, 
                            assignment_duration_in_seconds: 60 * 5,
                            max_assignments: 1, 
                            reward: "0.25", 
                            question: QUESTION)

p "Your HIT is created. The HIT ID is #{response.hit.hit_id}"
```